# Camel active mq - Producer to confirm if messages are processed by consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We have a producer service which is publishing a message to topic and we have 3 instances of consumers reading that message from topic. Producer needs to do further processing (update DB) only when all consumers processed and replied a success message in another reply queue. Even if one of the consumer service failed due to some exception or any failure message in reply queue, producer should not do update DB for that publish request.

For next request (new message published in topic), if all consumers processed and replied in reply queue, producer should update DB.  How can we achieve this with camel and activemq. Is there any EIP pattern(s) to achieve this?

Any

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the producer can just use the `aggregator` enterprise integration pattern on the reply queue to ensure all 3 consumers processed the previous message.

Doc: Apache Camel [aggregator2](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) component.

You will need a unique key and use a proper aggregation strategy.

Comment: Thanks Vikingsteve for your reply. The crux of the issue is producer is a separate camel route which is in different code base which deployed in open shift. Simalrly consumer camel route is different code base and deployed in open shift. Usually consumer is deployed as 3 - 4 instances  in open shift and request is load balanced by open shift platform. My problem is if we aggregator how long we can wait on the reply queue to confirm if all the consumers replied. What if 2 consumers replied in 5 sec and 3rd one took 1 hour to reply. In aggregator we should mention time out or on completion.

Comment: Yes you can and definitely should build in timeout. Have you had a look at some of the examples there on the camel site? The component is customizable with aggregation strategies